# PFBC Form syntax for new version?

Tags: php, forms, pfbc

I have a qiuck question.
`setValues()` and `setAttributes()` can be used for PFBC3.1-PFBC5.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `setAttribute($attribute, $value)` is still available for everything that extends `Base.php` (All elements, ErrorView, Form, Validation and view).

And `setValues(array $values)` is still available for `Form.php`

For example:

```
$textarea = new Element\Textarea("Textarea:", "Textarea");
$textarea->setAttribute('rows', 10);
$form->setValues(['Textarea'=>'lorem ipsum']);
$form->addElement($textarea);
```